# Button and drawable left

Tags: android, android-layout

I create button in xml file like this:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/call_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_weight="40" 
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/symbol_phone"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:drawablePadding="-25dp"
        android:text="Call"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
```

I would like to know how I can do drawableLeft in activity. I know that is stupid but I need do this in activity because I create button there. How I can do the same what  I have in xml file in my activity? I need add drawableLeft and drawable padding and padding left. 
This is how I create button in activity

```
 Button button1 = new Button(this);
 button1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(buttonWidth, buttonHeight));
 button1.setText(systemTexts.getShowCallButton());
 button1.setBackgroundDrawable(new                                      
 button1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(buttonTextColor));
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Drawable image = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon );
image.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );
button.setCompoundDrawables( image, null, null, null );
```

do this

**Update:**

Since *`getContext().getResources().getDrawable`* is now **deprecated**, use this instead:

```
  Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.icon);
  image.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );
  button.setCompoundDrawables( image, null, null, null );
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
Drawable icon= getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to programmatically set drawableLeft is with [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

You can set the padding with [setPadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

The docs show the corresponding java method for all xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
txtVw.setCompoundDrawables(R.drawable.img_nature, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code

```
<Button android:text="@string/button_label" 
android:id="@+id/buttonId"
android:layout_width="160dip"
android:layout_height="60dip"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSize="13dip"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
android:drawablePadding="2dip"
android:paddingLeft="30dip"
android:paddingRight="26dip"
android:singleLine="true"
android:gravity="center" />
```

It will manage by padding ti text and image both

Comment: I think you don't answer the question, the OP wanted to do it programmatically.